# How to inject dependency for hierarchy in Spring.Net

Tags: .net, configuration, dependency-injection, ioc-container, spring.net

How can I define configuration to inject dependencies to the following hierarchy of objects:

```
RootObject
 - ContentObject
   - L11Object
   - L12Object
     - L21Object
     .etc.
```

The `RootObject` has dependency to `ImportantObject` and `ContentObject` has dependency to `AnotherObject`.
To define theses dependencies I defined the following:

```xml
<object name="RootObject" type="...." abstract="true">
  <constructor-args ../>
</object>
<object name="ContentObject" type="...." abstract="true" parent="RootObject">
  <constructor-args ../>
</object>
```

All works fine, but Spring.Net requires define hierarchy of my's objects in configuration.
Is it posible to use somethink like "auto discovery" to do not repeate hierarchy of inheritance in configuration through define `parent="..."`?

And yes, I know that Unity 1.0+ solves it much better than Spring.Net, but I have no choice and I should use Spring.Net.

Comment: "Auto discovery" is called autowiring in spring.net: see the [spring.net docs on autowire](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#objects-factory-autowire).

Comment: The `parent` and `abstract` attributes you are using are not used to wire dependencies, but to reuse object definitions. That concept is called [object definition inheritance](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#objects-childobjects).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want **Auto-wiring**... Something like this ought to work:

```
<objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net"
         default-autowire="constructor">
  <object type="RootObject" />
  <object type="ContentObject" />
  <object type="L11Object" />
  <object type="L12Object" />
  <object type="L21Object" />
  <!--etc.-->
</objects>
```

This assumes that the types in question utilizes the **Constructor Injection** pattern, but IIRC **Property Injection** is also supported.

Even though the `default-autowire` defines a default behavior for Auto-wiring, you can still override it in those `object` elements where it might be required.

Comment: This is correct, but you will probably need to specify the full type name (including namespace and assembly).

Comment: According to the [docs](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#objects-factory-autowire), you should also be able to use `byName`, `byType` and `autodetect` for autowire mode, but when using `default-autowire` as above, only `constructor` worked for me.

Comment: So property injection apparently is available and might work, but I couldn't set it up within 15 minutes ... but that's just me.

Comment: Regarding the type name, you can define *type aliases* so that you don't have to write the assembly qualified name in the `objects` definition (but you'll still need to write it in the type alias definition).